# How to stop a for loop using a button?

Tags: c#, loops, button, for-loop

I have a loop that I would like to stop using a button.
Edited for better understanding:

I do realize that you cannot stop a button while a loop was running since it will not work as long as that current UI is running. What I'm really asking for is the most efficient way of creating a thread or using BGWorker to stop this. I have seen some methods, but most of them are for Java and not C#.

What I would like to do is:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    stops start_Click()
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do what you are asking unless you place your loop in another thread.  Your loop is blocking interaction to your button.

Comment: I know people won't like this but try it by putting `Application.DoEvents()` and checking a boolean variable in your loop :)

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF or something else?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. For starters, the `for` loop is running synchronously on the UI thread, which means you won't even be *able* to click the "Stop" button.

Hence, you need to move the operations of the for loop onto another thread, which means you likely won't be using a `for` loop at all. You need to think about how the code inside *actually* needs to be executed, then based on how you are doing the processing, you can implement the "Stop" button.

A very simple way to do this would be to just:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   int i = 0;
   while (!stop && i < num)
   {
      doSomething();
      i++;
   }
 }).Start();
```

And set `stop` to stop the processing loop. In a more realistic scenario, you could queue up functions that you want to process, then stop dequeuing via a similar method. Unfortunately, its hard to reccommend a setup without knowing more details.

Any solution based on your code will also have the problem of the current `doSomething()` completing execution (which could take a while). Again, without more info, its hard to say what the best approach to fixing that is.

Answer (score 5):

To keep your UI responsive to be able to cancel the running operation you can use a backgrounworker.
The backgroundworker does the work in an other thread while keeping your UI responsive:

```
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        Disposed += Form1_Disposed;
    }

    private void Form1_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _backgroundWorker.Dispose();
    }

    private void StartLoop()
    {
        if ( !_backgroundWorker.IsBusy )
        {
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void StopLoop()
    {
        _backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork( object sender , DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {
        var backgroundWorker = ( BackgroundWorker ) sender;

        for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        {
            if ( backgroundWorker.CancellationPending )
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            // Do Work
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.Cancelled )
        {
            // handle cancellation
        }
        if ( e.Error != null )
        {
            // handle error
        }

        // completed without cancellation or exception
    }
```

Comment: This is great! Although I'd rather have a way to do it in multi-threading, this helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: check this on MSDN it clearly shows some possibilities you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8chs7ft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it's likely the best approach here is to convert your work to an asynchronous operation and then use the `async`/`await` idiom for the loop. E.g.:

```
private bool _stopLoop;

private async void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stopLoop = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums && !_stopLoop; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => doSomething());
    }
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stopLoop = true;
}
```

This allows the loop itself to execute in the UI thread where the `_stopLoop` variable is being managed, but without actually blocking the UI thread (which among other things would prevent the "Stop" button from being clicked).

Unfortunately, you didn't provide details about how `doSomething()` works. It's possible there's a good way to convert that whole method to be an `async` method, but I can't comment on that without the actual code.

Note that this approach will only interrupt the loop at a point in between each operation. If you want to be able to interrupt the `doSomthing()` operation itself, you'll have to provide a mechanism for that. One likely approach would be to use `CancellationSource` and `CancellationToken`, which provides a convenient way to express cancellation semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an async/await approach. It's quite easy!

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    private async void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tokenSource != null)
            return;

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ct = _tokenSource.Token;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
                doSomething();
            }
        }, ct);

        _tokenSource = null;
    }

    private int _labelCounter;

    private void doSomething()
    {
        // do something
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            myLabel.Text = (++_labelCounter).ToString();
        }));
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tokenSource == null)
            return;

        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010, and cannot use async/await. Is downloading the newer version worth it, or will I not be able to run previous programs using 2013?

Comment: It's not a problem, MS tries to keep a full backward compatibility in such cases. Your project will be converted to VS 2013 project, than you should choose a corresponding targer framework (e.g. 4.5.1) in project properties. That's all.
Async/await is a great simplification of async ui programming, it's worth it.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
bool stop=false;

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for(int i = 0; i < nums&& !bool; i++)
{
doSomething();
}
}
```

and in the click event

set

```
stop=true;
```

Comment: Won't work, the UI thread is blocked. This works if executed on a *separate* thread, but that can cause other issues...

Comment: This won't work, as the UI is already running a current task and will not run a seperate one until this is finished.