# Catching cancel button click between two synchronous tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a list of tasks running and would like to show the progress in a (WinForms) form with a Cancel button.

I am aware, that there are several `async` options, but I have two restraints: The tasks must not run on a separate thread and the solution must be compatible with .NET 3.5 (it is an AddIn for a program, I have no access to).

It is fine, if one task finishes, before the cancellation comes into force. So I wonder, if there is some chance to check in synchronous code, if a mouse click on a button happened while having performed some task?

edit: This is the intended code:

```
foreach (IStep step in Steps)
{
    if (Cancelled)
        return;
    step.Run();
    ReportProgress(100.0 * completedWeight / totalWeight, step.Description);
    completedWeight += step.Weight;
}

ReportProgress(100, "Completed");
```

So `IStep` contains a `Run()` method, and I am perfectly fine with completing a step before cancelling. I do not know how to catch mouse click on the Cancel button while executing some step to set `Cancelled` to `true`.

Comment: What is the code that is executed? Is it 1 line of code executing long time or a loop or multiple lines of codes? If it is loop or multiline and you can't find appropriate way to do this, the quick and dirty way is to add a boolean, set it to true on cancel click and check inside the loop if(cancel == true) break; (or return whatever your code is)

Comment: This is my intention, see edit above. I do not know how I can catch the click on the button to set `Cancelled` to `true`

Comment: "The tasks must not run on a separate thread" - this makes it very difficult to provide a good user experience. You could perhaps run the message loop explicitly, but you would need to do so every 50ms or so, and that just sounds like a terrible solution to me. Why do you have such a requirement?

Comment: The operations (of `IStep`) are performed on a database, which can absolutely not handle multiple accesses. There is no way to block the main thread starting accesses randomly except executing the operations on the main thread.
However, I might be able to start the progress form on a side thread and get it updated by the main thread (this is the opposite of the usual way, but I suppose this is fine). As a starter, I have removed the Cancel button for now. (;

Comment: @st_stefanov But this click_event is only executed after my loop is finished, isn’t it?

Comment: Yeah, in your case it won't work. May be you've seen this, but check it if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608357/how-to-stop-a-for-loop-using-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is no "standard" solution here, so we have to think outside the box...

Say you have your application (AddIn or whatever, doesn't matter) and you can't control the loop from a button.

You read/write to the database.

On top of your loop, where it says:

```
if (Cancelled)
        return;
```

We have to replace with:

```
If(CheckIsCancelled())
```

You have to find a way to make a button that can be clicked, either another form near the current one, but it must be able to run independently from the current form that is blocked by your loop.

Create a database parameter in some sort of Config/Util table.
E.g. `CancelMyLoop - Bit`

On that button click - set the parameter value to `true`.

And back to the method: `CheckIsCancelled()`
it will go in the db and read that value every time.

Downside is performance, but you want the impossible so you have to settle with a workaround like this...

You can create your own implementation, just giving you an idea.

Comment: My old solution was a bit similar, where the tasks did remain on the main thread, but the progress bar did run on another thread. This works, but makes all the handling of the progress a bit more difficult, then it needs to be, if run synchronously. However, I accept your answer, since this comes most close to what I will use in the end. (: